# Cannot find module './client/Client' discord bot error

Tags: node.js, module, bots, discord.js

```
$ node index.js
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:895
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './client/Client'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\INO\Desktop\discord-bot-master\index.js
←[90m    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892
:15)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:785:27)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:19)←[39m
←[90m    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)←[39m
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\INO\Desktop\discord-bot-master\index.js:3:16
)
←[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)←[39m
←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1103:1
0)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:914:32)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:822:14)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1143:12)←[39
m {
  code: ←[32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'←[39m,
  requireStack: [ ←[32m'C:\\Users\\INO\\Desktop\\discord-bot-master\\index.js'←[
39m ]
}
```

That's the error I keep getting.

I've tried everything and looked everywhere and I've spend 10 hours on this. 
My files are not corrupt :,,)
I've consistently come back to this site and every answer has not worked.

Comment: Can you show the code in index.js

Comment: Code was too long to copy and paste so I took screenshots. Here: https://sta.sh/2mtha6grjk8

Comment: Looking to our screens and the error you getting there must be something wrong because on your screens you don't have `'./client/Client'` on line 3

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out.

My issue was running index.js without installing all of the dependencies.

choco install python -y

choco install visualstudio2019buildtools -y

choco install visualstudio2017community -y

npm install --global --production windows-build-tools --vs2015

npm install --global windows-build-tools@4.0.0

npm install -g node-gyp

npm install --save windows-build-tools

node index.js

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).